# how to achieve the same extern C++ effect in Python?

Tags: python

Is there a way to write Python like this? I want to use it before assigning value in the same file:

```
extern ws2
def myfunc(ws2)
   print(ws2)
ws2= '''
    more than 200 chars
    more than 200 chars
    '''
```

In C++ we can write such code
**(the following code is in the same file)**:

```
extern std::wstring ws2;
void func()
{
  std::wcout << ws2 << std::endl;
}
std::wstring ws2(L"...more than 200 chars");
```

Comment: @MartijnPieters, could you cancel your downvote? I think my question is clear now.

Comment: @O'Skywalker: who says I voted? Please don't ask people to upvote or change votes. Votes are a personal choice and *usually* reflect how people feel about different aspects of your post.

Comment: @O'Skywalker didn't downvote

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The exact same thing would work, as long as you used the string later in time than when it was defined. Using it inside a function and declaring it at module level is usually like that:

```
def func():
    print(ws2)

ws2 = 'more than 200 chars...'
```

would work fine.

That said, this would be *harder* to read, not idiomatic, and would break if you called that function at module level before the string was defined.

I would use the fact that multiple string literals immediately after each other are parsed as a single string literal (just like in C), and define constants always at the top of the module:

```
WS2 = (
   "some part of the string"
   "another part"
   "on and on until we have all 200 characters."
)

def func():
```

(I also put the name in caps because it's a module level constant)